# Get UUID of a USB Mass Storage Device connected to an Android device

Tags: android, usb, usbmanager

I have been going though the Android documentation searching for a way to identify a USB device (mass storage device or other) by its UUID, but I don't find one.

I looked at:

- [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice) Docs
- [UsbManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager) Docs
- [USB Dev](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html) guide

Non of these provide a sufficient method of determing the UUID.

Looking at some of the methods in [UsbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice), I would possibly go for [getDeviceID()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice#getDeviceId()), however it

> Returns a unique integer ID for the device. This is a convenience for
>   clients that want to use an integer to represent the device, rather
>   than the device name. IDs are not persistent across USB disconnects.

*As a side note, I am using [this library (libaums)](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums) to communicate with a FAT32 USB Mass Storage Device*

How can I get the UUID of a USB mass storage device on an Android phone?

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getSerialNumber() should uniquely identify the device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -> will only work for API +21 `Added in API level 21`. I need to support API +16. Thanks again